# Access denied for files owned by apache

Tags: linux, apache, ssh, vps

I am trying to migrate data from onw of my VPS to another. The problem is, for the VPS from where I am moving the files, I don't have root access, and most of the user uploaded content in there are owned by apache, and hence when I tried `rsync` I got `access denied`. I tried chown from the account I do have access to, but it seems that account can't change the owner of those files(but I might be doing it wrong as well, since I am new to SSH. So please tell me the correct syntax to recursively change ownership of all files within a folder and subfolders. I tried `chown -R dirname/*`). So is there any other way to move these files?

Also, if I reset the password(I am on godaddy linux-VPS), will it affect my site or cause any downtimes? If I get root access, will it help in this matter?

Comment: mail this issue to the service provider. They will deal with it. I dont think that they will give you root access. Instead they will change the file permissions

Comment: I tried contacting them, but they won't do it. i am on my own here

Comment: It's `chown <user>:<group> dirname/* -R` were `<user>` and `<group>` are placeholders.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resetting your password on your Go Daddy Linux VPS should not cause any downtime. The password reset should just change the user and root passwords.  Once you are logged in to the server as your user you will then use the "su" command to change to the root user.  You cannot log in directly as root.  The command will look like this:

```
 #su -
```

Once logged in as root you should be able to do the rsync without issues.